# About static variable and complicated use in java

Tags: java, static

```
public class TestA {
    static int x;
    static TestA a;
    static TestB b;

    TestA() { x++;}

    static void runTest() {
        a = new TestA();
        b = new TestB();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runTest();
        runTest();
        System.out.println(a.x);
        System.out.println(b.x);
        System.out.println(a.x + b.x);
    }
}

class TestB extends TestA {
    static int x;
    TestB(){ x += 2;}
}
```

The result of this code is :
4
4
8
May I ask why? I tried to understand it by drawing a graph. But it never makes sense. How can x be changed to 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `new TestA()`, the `TestA` constructor runs.

When you call `new TestB()`, the `TestB` constructor **and** the `TestA` constructors both run.

The `x` seen by the `TestA` constructor is not the same `x` seen by the `TestB` constructor. If you change the two constructors to this, they would still do the same:

```
TestA() { TestA.x++;}

TestB(){ TestB.x += 2;}
```

Also, using instance variable to access a static field is highly discouraged, so although it's allowed, you should never do it. The compiler replaces the instance variable with the appropriate class for static access, *as seen by the compiler*. That means your print statements compile to the same as this:

```
System.out.println(TestA.x);
System.out.println(TestB.x);
System.out.println(TestA.x + TestB.x);
```

Finally, you call `runTest()` twice, and each call will execute the `TestA` constructor twice, and the `TestB` constructor once, so all in all, you execute the `TestA` constructor 4 times, and the `TestB` constructor 2 times.

Result:
4 times `TestA.x++` means `TestA.x = 4`
2 times `TestB.x += 2` means `TestB.x = 4`

That is why the program output is:

```
4
4
8
```